# Bonjour Avahi daemon TXTRecord

Tags: service, updates, daemon, bonjour, avahi

I try to use txt-records to share information between multiple devices. Therefore I am using bonjour/avahi. The server-side works fine as wireshark proofs. Information is added to the txt-record and sent out using MDNS.
The problem occurs on the client side, where the daemon/service does not seem to get the information change all the time. It is stuck with information that is already outdated and does not automatically update it when I try to resolve the service again.

On the client side I am using DNSServiceResolve in combination with a callback function where I call TXTRecordContainsKey and TXTRecordGetValuePtr to make sure the data is available before use. This all works fine except that, as already mentioned, the information is not always updated.

Am I missing something, or are there any additional API-function calls that I can use to force the daemon to update its record except DNSServiceResolve?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, always make sure you deaktivate your firewall when dealing with such strange problems...
This completely solved my issue.